# Qt3D: How to colour lines?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

In a scene I have a line and a cylinder. For each entity, I use a QDiffuseSpecularMaterial component. For each material, I set **only** the diffuse property to be the colour yellow (not setting any values for the ambient, normal and specular properties). The result is the following:

The cylinder is yellow, but the line is black

[image]

If I modify the material used for the line and set the ambient colour to be yellow, the line will be yellow.

Both the cylinder and the line are yellow

[image]

Nevertheless, in this scenario, if I set the linear attenuation for the light entity, I will get the following result:

The cylinder is affected by the light attenuation, but the line is not

[image]

Why the material works differently for these two entities and how can I fix this?

The code used to create the line:

```
auto *geometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(_rootEntity);

QByteArray bufferBytes;
bufferBytes.resize(3 * 2 * sizeof(float)); 
float *positions = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bufferBytes.data());
*positions++ = start.x();
*positions++ = start.y();
*positions++ = start.z();
*positions++ = end.x();
*positions++ = end.y();
*positions++ = end.z();

auto *buf = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
buf->setData(bufferBytes);

auto *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
positionAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
positionAttribute->setVertexSize(3);
positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
positionAttribute->setBuffer(buf);
positionAttribute->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float));
positionAttribute->setCount(2);
geometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute); 


QByteArray indexBytes;
indexBytes.resize(2 * sizeof(unsigned int)); // start to end
unsigned int *indices = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(indexBytes.data());
*indices++ = 0;
*indices++ = 1;

auto *indexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry);
indexBuffer->setData(indexBytes);

auto *indexAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry);
indexAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedInt);
indexAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);
indexAttribute->setBuffer(indexBuffer);
indexAttribute->setCount(2);
geometry->addAttribute(indexAttribute); 

// mesh
auto *line = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(_rootEntity);
line->setGeometry(geometry);
line->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Lines);
auto *material = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial(_rootEntity);
material->setDiffuse(color);

//material->setAmbient(color);

// entity
auto *lineEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(_rootEntity);
lineEntity->addComponent(line);
lineEntity->addComponent(material);
```

The code used to create the cylinder:

```
// Cylinder shape data
Qt3DExtras::QCylinderMesh *cylinder = new Qt3DExtras::QCylinderMesh();
cylinder->setRadius(1);
cylinder->setLength(3);
cylinder->setRings(100);
cylinder->setSlices(20);

// CylinderMesh Transform
Qt3DCore::QTransform *cylinderTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
cylinderTransform->setScale(1.5f);
cylinderTransform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 45.0f));
cylinderTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-5.0f, 4.0f, -1.5));

Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial *cylinderMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial();
cylinderMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor("yellow"));

// Cylinder
auto m_cylinderEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
m_cylinderEntity->addComponent(cylinder);
m_cylinderEntity->addComponent(cylinderMaterial);
m_cylinderEntity->addComponent(cylinderTransform);
```